# Expand table (rows and col) in excel reference to another cell

Tags: excel

Is there a way to automatically add rows and columns based on a ref cell.

Example in a cell if the number is 8 I need to create a table 8*8

basically I am trying to find the solution to this question. Below is the table to add the values of two 6 sided dice. But now if I want to find 8 face dice is there a way to automatically do it in excel, without adding the col,row 7&8 then doing the calculation

[table for the adding two 6 faced dice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2yVb.png)

Apologize if I am not clear but I can not find the answer for this. I am thinking about creating a Macro but is there a way to do it without that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you started the table in A1, in B2 the formula should be =B$1+$A2. You can then copy the formula to as big as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was looking more of an automatic way to do it. like if in a cell if I type the face of the dice, ex 6 that table is created and the formula is automatically gets filled in the table 6 x 6. I saw someone do it, I just cant figure it out

Comment: If it's a table, then the formula should automatically fill in if you enter additional rows